# Playing a gif within an Android widget application

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable, animated-gif, android-remoteview

I am working on a project where I have a requirement to play a gif in an Android widget `ImageView`. For this purpose I have tried all the possible ways by using `Glide` and libraries like 
https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView
https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

**Problems I am facing**

1. **Glide** -  I couldn't load gif into an `ImageView` because of a `RemoteView` property (i.e only bitmaps and resources can be assigned, Not drawables)
2. Libraries - I couldn't use any third party libraries because all libraries extends `View` (Since `RemoteView` doesn't support `View` in the layout), CustomView cannot be also implemented because there is no ways to assign or call custom methods (Since `setImageViewResource` and `setImageViewBitmap` are only possible methods revealed in `RemoteView`)

**What I am trying to do:**

Since I couldn't find any solution for this requirement, so I am trying to do my own methodology by downloading and breaking gif into multiple frames as `Bitmap` and then planning to use those frames in the `RemoteView`. Kindly help me if any other solutions can be implemented to achieve this feature. I have been working on this since for the past 7 days, but couldn't find any solutions for my requirement. Any sort of tips and suggestion would be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can load gif from drawables using glide.

Comment: can you help me understand, how RemoteView is coming into the picture?

Comment: Also, does it have to be an ImageView or you can use other widgets like WebView?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use ImageViews to load gif, with this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
Glide.with(this).load(YOUR_GIF).into(imageViewTarget);
```

Comment: Actually in remote view, You can assign any values into imageview.

Comment: RemoteView remote = new RemoteView(this,R.layout.views);

Comment: remote.setImageBitmap(R.id.imageView,bitmap)

Comment: you have to assign like in the above ways.

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question in context of remote view. This is not the right way to set image on image view when it's placed on remote view